# Firebase: The email address is already in use by another account. (auth/email-already-in-use)

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication

> Firebase: The email address is already in use by another account. (auth/email-already-in-use).

This error is coming from firebase and everything works, but, i would like to diplay error without firebase name there, how can i do that?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  It is customary to include in your question the code you are working with so that we can see what you have so far and help you proceed with that.   Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thank you, i will do better next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Capture your error with error code :

```
if(errorCode == "auth/email-already-in-use"){
    alert("Email already in use")
}
```

Comment: the problem is that for some reason the exception is being thrown 2 times so even if i handle the createUserWithEmailAndPassword a different one is being thrown

Answer (score 3):

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  .then((userCredential) => {
    // Signed in 
    var user = userCredential.user;
    // ...
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    if (error.code == "auth/email-already-in-use") {
        alert("The email address is already in use");
    } else if (error.code == "auth/invalid-email") {
        alert("The email address is not valid.");
    } else if (error.code == "auth/operation-not-allowed") {
        alert("Operation not allowed.");
    } else if (error.code == "auth/weak-password") {
        alert("The password is too weak.");
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just split your error message because the actual message is after the first space character.

```
error.substring(error.indexOf(' ') + 1);
```